# Command Line - how to extract a file name only when using a for command loop

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, dos

What I need to do is extract the filename from %%f so I can create the correct dll name.

```
for %%f in (*.asmx.cs) do (
    echo %%f

    cmd /c C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:library /r:%assemblies% %compileoptions% /out:bin/%%f.dll %%f
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use %%~nf.

```
for %%f in (*.asmx.cs) do (
    echo %%~nf

    cmd /c C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:library /r:%assemblies% %compileoptions% /out:bin/%%~nf.dll %%f
)
```

For a complete list of FOR variable modifiers like %%~nf, run `for /?` from the command line, or look online [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true).